# Why my tcl thread exit when ::thread::wait is present?

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I'm trying to understand the working of thread:wait from the below code

```
set logger [thread::create {
   proc OpenLog {file} {
   global fid
   set fid [open $file a]
} proc CloseLog {} {
   global fid
   close $fid
} proc AddLog {
   msg} {
   global fid
   puts $fid $msg
} thread::wait
}]

% ::thread::exists $logger
0
```

Why the above code does not wait for even and exit on the spot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your thread-creation script has some syntax errors in it, making it fail to start up correctly; it dies asynchronously and prints an error message. That error seems to be going missing in your case; no idea why, but it ought to read something like:

```
Error from thread tid0x100481000
wrong # args: should be "proc name args body"
    while executing
"proc OpenLog {file} {
   global fid
   set fid [open $file a]
} proc CloseLog {} {
   global fid
   close $fid
} proc AddLog {
   msg} {
   global fid..."
```

If we correct the obvious syntax problems, *converting spaces to newlines where it matters*, then we can get this which appears to work for me:

```
set logger [thread::create {
   proc OpenLog {file} {
      global fid
      set fid [open $file a]
   }
   proc CloseLog {} {
      global fid
      close $fid
   }
   proc AddLog {msg} {
      global fid
      puts $fid $msg
   }
   thread::wait
}]
```

**The only differences are to whitespace.** Tcl cares about whitespace. Get it right.

Comment: Also, I could have used `;` in some places to fix this too. It's just not usually regarded as being the greatest Tcl style to use it a lot.